# Unable to perform a prepared query using class

Tags: php, class, pdo, prepared-statement

I would like to make a CRUD class, for inserting, updating and deleting data, in the __contruct function,  I don't want to call the connection, I would only specify the connection name, then I am getting this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function prepare
>   () on a non-object in crud.php on line 60

```
<?php

/* Start (config.php)
This part of code is only to show you that the connection name is "connexion" which is called in config.php

$connexion = new PDO('mysql:host='.$db_host.';dbname='.$db_name, $db_user, $db_passwd
        , array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES '.$db_charset.'')); //SET NAMES utf8
$connexion->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);

EnD */
```

classDB.php

```
require_once('config.php');

final class crud {

    public function __construct($connexionName) {

        $this->connexionName  = $connexionName;
    }

    public final function insert($tableName, $fields=array()){

        $this->tableName = $tableName;
        $this->fields    = $fields;

        foreach ($this->fields as $kf => $vf) {

            $inKeys[]       = $kf;
            $inKeysDotted[] = ':' . $kf;

            $insertedKeys       = implode(', ', $inKeys);
            $insertedKeysDotted = implode(', ', $inKeysDotted);


        }

            echo '<br />';

        $sql = "INSERT INTO $this->tableName ($insertedKeys) VALUES ($insertedKeysDotted)";
        $insertItems = $this->connexionName->prepare("$sql"); // THIS IS LINE 60

        echo 'insert '.$insertItems.'<br />';

} // end insert()


} // end CRUD


$con = new crud($connexion);

echo '<br />';

$con->insert('ban_ip', array('visitor_type'=>'5', 'ip'=>'111.222.333.444'));

?>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you put your PDO part as comments in your actual code?

Comment: I edited the above code

Comment: on line 59 when you add `var_dump($this->connexionName);` it shows `object(PDO)[30]` ??

Comment: Eh try to add connexionName, tableNames, fields as a property to the class and do not just declare them dynamically

Comment: Where exactly is line 59?

Comment: @Clayton: yes that is the result

Comment: @frz3993: line 59 is $sql = "

Comment: what does this show you: `var_dump(get_class_methods($this->connexionName));`

Comment: array (size=17)
  0 => string '__construct' (length=11)
  1 => string 'prepare' (length=7)
  2 => string 'beginTransaction' (length=16)
  3 => string 'commit' (length=6)
  4 => string 'rollBack' (length=8)
  5 => string 'inTransaction' (length=13)
  6 => string 'setAttribute' (length=12)
  7 => string 'exec' (length=4)
  8 => string 'query' (length=5)
  9 => string 'lastInsertId' (length=12)
  10 => string 'errorCode' (length=9)
  11 => string 'errorInfo' (length=9)
  12 => string 'getAttribute' (length=12)
  13 => string 'quote' (length=5)
  14 => string '__wakeup' (length=8)

Comment: One of the problems..You create an instance after the property call..$con = new crud($connexion);

Comment: It's done, but still cannot be connected

Comment: What's the new error an update to your question maybe helpful..

Comment: well aaronxxx, I just do it as a classic method, while learning more about PDO, thanks to everybody